# Why ingress always return 502 Error to specific service nodeport only?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, gke-networking

I have an alpine docker image to run my raw PHP website on an apache server(PHP 7.4) `EXPOSE 80`.
I want to run the image on Kubernetes(GKE) with an ingress controller.
I'm pushing the image with gcloud command to the google container registry.
Both the deployment and service have no errors and created successfully as NodePort.
The ingress I deployed is from google tutorials(https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke)
In my ingress now there is:

- 34.68.78.46.xip.io/
- 34.68.78.46.xip.io/hello
- 34.68.78.46.xip.io/jb(/|$)(.*)

The /hello is the same configuration of the tutorial and it is working fine.
The /jb is the same configuration as I mentioned below and always returning 502 Error.
Ingress details in the GCP console show no warnings or errors

I have checked:
[Kubernetes GKE Ingress : 502 Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66110561/kubernetes-gke-ingress-502-server-error)
[GKE Ingress: 502 error when downloading file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49540280/gke-ingress-502-error-when-downloading-file)
[502 Server Error Google kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50368210/502-server-error-google-kubernetes)

Here is the deployment file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jomlahbazar-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      greeting: jomlah
      department: bazar
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        greeting: jomlah
        department: bazar
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: jomlah
        image: "us.gcr.io/third-nature-273904/jb-img-1-0:v1"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: "PORT"
          value: "80"
```

Here is the service file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jomlahbazar-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    greeting: jomlah
    department: bazar
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

Here in the ingress file:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-resource
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url : "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: 34.68.78.46.xip.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: jomlahbazar-service
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /hello
        backend:
          serviceName: hello-app
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /jb(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: jomlahbazar-service
          servicePort: 80
```

Here is the ingress description:

```
Name:             ingress-resource
Namespace:        default
Address:          34.68.78.46
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (10.20.1.6:8080)
Rules:
  Host                Path  Backends
  ----                ----  --------
  34.68.78.46.xip.io
                      /              jomlahbazar-service:80 (<none>)
                      /hello         hello-app:8080 (10.20.2.61:8080)
                      /jb(/|$)(.*)   jomlahbazar-service:80 (<none>)
Annotations:
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class:                       nginx
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url:          true
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target:        /$2
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect:          false
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex:             true
  kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:  {"apiVersion":"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{"kubernetes.io/ingress.class":"nginx","nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url":"true","nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target":"/$2","nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect":"false","nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex":"true"},"name":"ingress-resource","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"rules":[{"host":"34.68.78.46.xip.io","http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"serviceName":"jomlahbazar-service","servicePort":80},"path":"/"},{"backend":{"serviceName":"hello-app","servicePort":8080},"path":"/hello"},{"backend":{"serviceName":"jomlahbazar-service","servicePort":80},"path":"/jb(/|$)(.*)"}]}}]}}

Events:
  Type    Reason          Age                 From                      Message
  ----    ------          ----                ----                      -------
  Normal  AddedOrUpdated  36m (x6 over 132m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Configuration for default/ingress-resource was added or updated
```

The output of kubectl get ing ingress-resource -o yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"networking.k8s.io/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{"kubernetes.io/ingress.class":"nginx","nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url":"true","nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target":"/$2","nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect":"false","nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex":"true"},"name":"ingress-resource","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"rules":[{"host":"34.68.78.46.xip.io","http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"serviceName":"jomlahbazar-service","servicePort":80},"path":"/"},{"backend":{"serviceName":"hello-app","servicePort":8080},"path":"/hello"},{"backend":{"serviceName":"jomlahbazar-service","servicePort":80},"path":"/jb(/|$)(.*)"}]}}]}}
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
  creationTimestamp: "2021-02-11T06:00:07Z"
  generation: 5
  name: ingress-resource
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "2195351"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/ingresses/ingress-resource
  uid: 74dc822f-91cb-4902-991b-1ad298f44ae6
spec:
  rules:
  - host: 34.68.78.46.xip.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: jomlahbazar-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
      - backend:
          serviceName: hello-app
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /hello
      - backend:
          serviceName: jomlahbazar-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /jb(/|$)(.*)
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 34.68.78.46
```

Comment: There is misconfiguration in your deployment. Instead of  `env.name.value: "80"` you should have `env.name.value: "8080"`. I will elaborate soon as answer.

Comment: This is definitely an error yes. I changed it but still, I get the 502 error. Should I delete the deployment and service then create again with different names or should configuring them do just fine? Because I can still see the same backend services.

Comment: I fixed what you noted and edited the question info again, the 502 error is still showing.

Answer (score 1):

I've run some tests on my GKE cluster. I've replicate your behavior using 2 hello world applications v1 and v2.

### Scenario 1

HW 1

```
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello1
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

SVC HW1

```
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    key: app
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
```

HW 2

```
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello2
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:2.0
        env:
        - name: "PORT"
          value: "80"
```

SVC HW2

```
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: hello2
```

Ingress

```
spec:
  rules:
  -  http:
      paths:
      - path: /hello2
        backend:
          serviceName: h2
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /hello
        backend:
          serviceName: fs
          servicePort: 80
```

Outputs:

```
$ curl 34.117.70.75/hello
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: fd-c6d79cdf8-7rmmd

$ curl 34.117.70.75/hello2

<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>502 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Server Error</h1>
<h2>The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
```

In this scenario, deployment was configured to create pod which will listen on `port: 80`. As you skipped configureing `containerPort` in deployment, Kubernetes automatically used the same port in `containerPort` as was set in `port`. You can verify it using `netstat` command.

```
$ kubectl exec -ti h2-deploy-6dbf5b7899-g7rbj -- bin/sh
/ # netstat -plnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1/hello-app
/ #
```

In your service you set `containerPort: 8080`, so service expect traffic to go trought port `8080`. As pod is listening only on `80` and traffic goes trought `8080` you are getting `502` error.

### Scenario 2

After change value from "80" to "8080" and apply new configuration.

```
$ curl 34.117.70.75/hello
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: fd-c6d79cdf8-7rmmd

$ curl 34.117.70.75/hello2
Hello, world!
Version: 2.0.0
Hostname: h2-deploy-5f5ccfbf9f-fjhrb
```

Netstat:

```
$ kubectl exec -ti f2-deploy-5f5ccfbf9f-fjhrb -- bin/sh
/ # netstat -plnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      1/hello-app
```

### Solution

**Solution 1**

You should change your application deployment to:

```
        env:
        - name: "PORT"
          value: "8080"
```

and apply new configuration.

**Solution 2**
Use `containerPort`

```
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: jb
        image: "us.gcr.io/third-nature-273904/jb-img-1-0:v3"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

**Note**

Please note, if you created your own image and used `EXPOSE` in your `Dockerfile`, you should configure your Deployment to use this specific port.

Let me know if you still have issue.

Comment: Ok you mean in the docker file It should be EXPOSE 8080, right?

Comment: Could you also share `netstat -plnt` output from your `jb` pod?

Comment: I already started a fresh configuration. I will update you asap. And thank you a lot.

Comment: I've tested your configuration and it's working on my cluster. Only thing different is your image. Maybe you have `EXPOSE` in dockerfile with specific port like 1234, in that situation you will need to configure your deployment and svc to align with this number.

Comment: I was exposing the image to 80 now I changed to 8080 too

Comment: So if the image is exposed on port 80, then you should: in deployment set port value: 80, service `targetPort: 80` and service `port` should be the same as ingress `servicePort`.

Comment: Yes, that makes a lot of sense, So just to be sure exposed port = port value = target port = service port = 80 is what should I do in my scenario.

Comment: In application, value of `EXPOSED` port should be the same as `targetPort` in `service` and `containerPort ` in `deployment`. If you will use only `port` in deployment, kubernetes will assign `deployment containerPort` the same value as `port`. Please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63448062/difference-between-container-port-and-targetport-in-kubernetes) for better `containerPort` and `targetPort` explanation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228532/discussion-between-ibrahim-and-pjoters).

Comment: Another thing why you are getting 404 is mostly related to the request that your `Pod` is receiving. By default `Ingress GKE` does not do any type of rewrite and passes the whole path to your `Pod`. Helloworld is just application which write some text, but Nginx or Apache is webserver.  You would need to change your apache configuration or use `Nginx Ingress controller` with [Rewrite](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/)

Comment: Please try to deploy nginx ingress controller on your GKE cluster like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59824278/i-have-deployed-pods-withs-its-service-and-i-am-getting-failed-to-connect-to-po/59875640#59875640) with `nginx` annotation and add `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /` annotation. And adjust ingress to your svc names. Let me know if this resolved your issue